# Rmagick resize and flatten_image error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui, rmagick

I am trying to use Rmagick to combine two images.

1. The image on top can be resized and dragged using Jquery-UI. I get size of the image after resize using Jquery code such as follows:

   ```
     ui.size["height"] and ui.size["width"]
   ```
2. I send this data using Ajax to Rails server.
3. The next step I resize the image using Rmagick resize_to_fit and then use flatten_image to combine the two images as follows:

   ```
   images=ImageList.new(img1, img2)
   images[1]=images[1].resize_to_fit!(height, width)
   images[1].page=Rectangle.new(height, width, x_coord+offset, y_coord-offset1)
   com_img=images.flatten_images
   com_img.write(tmpfile.path)
   ```

My problem is that the resize image does not seem to work correctly. I am always getting an image smaller than what I want (for different heights and widths tested by resizing image). The image's left top corner is correctly placed (meaning page command is working correctly).  I checked my Jquery UI code and ajax and its sending the correct size information. Somehow the information is not being processed correctly by Rmagick resize or flatten_image.

Can someone provide pointers what could be wrong here?

Thanks!

PS: Offsets account for the first image's position with respect to page top-left corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem Rmagick requires the images when they are resized that they should fit into a square. So the resize_to_fit function works correctly when both dimensions are the same and are the larger one among height or width.

So I changed the code to do the following

```
        if height > width
        images[1]=images[1].resize_to_fit!(height, height)
        else
        images[1]=images[1].resize_to_fit!(width, width)
        end
```